# way to globally add timestamps to terminal output?

Tags: linux, timestamp, ksh

I am trying to find a way to have all terminal output from .ksh scripts to have a time stamp pre-pended to the beginning of the line. The challenge is, the scripts I want to add these time stamps to are called from a proprietary orchestration tool on another server, which uses an agent on the server with the .ksh scripts to invoke the scripts. So, because I am not directly invoking the scripts, I cannot pipe the scripts to ts from moreutils, or to awk, which are the most common solutions I am seeing to this problem. I could alter the individual scripts, but this would be difficult given the amount of them, so I want to explore more of a global setting approach first.

Is there a way I can globally change this in one location, like through the .kshrc file for instance?

Comment: Formal note: it's basically a cross-post of [this question of yours](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/684081/108618). The wording is different but the problem seems pretty much the same. Cross-posting is [discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310).

Comment: Thank you for the note. This post was meant to add more detail to better describe the issue, as the other post gave some information that I've since realized doesn't exactly match the problem (ex. there are some log lines that are not from "echo" commands but instead from other programs called from the script). I thought a clearer post could lead to discussion that could lead to a solution.

Comment: Would changing the prompt to date-time help? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148550/how-can-i-get-kornshell-to-display-the-date-and-time-in-the-prompt

Comment: I don't think so, i missed another key detail, that agent on the server gathers the output into logs, which is ultimately where I want the time stamp to show up. So having it in the prompt wouldn't be in those gathered logs.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and add what you missed.

Comment: So "to terminal output" is misleading. Not "to terminal" but "to logs". What if a script is piped to another tool? Making the script print with timestamps may break what the other tool does. We could invent something that behaves differently when the output is to a regular file, than to a pipe; but I understand no script writes directly to a log, there is an agent in between, so never a regular file. How many logs are there? Are they with fixed paths? Is there `logrotate` or something similar? Can you configure the paths? My idea is to replace logs with fifos and then like `<fifo ts >realLog`.

Comment: `$ man syslog` ??